# I have lost my account and cannot sign in

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have not been active if I have not logged in or had control of my Google account which Google is currently investigating for months. I am sorry I have not reported it earlier but I have been busy trying to vet things back. It all started with dropping my tablet with full Knox enabled. My computer crashed while flashing my Nexus 6 while switching networks. I have more screenshots that prove something weird is happening.

> [image: screenshot]

What do I do to re-gain my account and stature; Thank you.

Edit: Email. That's a burn is myangels9988 same domain as original account but my reachable account.

Answer (score 1):

Only Stack Exchange staff can merge an account. From the screenshot, assuming that you are [this user](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/116800), please use the [contact form](https://android.stackexchange.com/contact) to report this.

From the [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts),

> #### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://android.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Comment: The issue I am having is that I cannot sign into my account because I enabled stackauth to simply sign in. I do not have the ability to sign into my google account then login. Google is currently doing a review so I will BA able to get back what I have lost due to a really bad day; Thank you.

Comment: Email. That's a burn is myangels9988 same domain as my account

Comment: I suggest waiting until you hear back from Google. If Google refuses your recovery request, please [post a new meta question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and maybe we can offer you more advice.

Comment: Andrew T. @unforgettableidSupportsMonica I have regained control of my account. Google finished their investigation. I humbly ask that my accounts be merged. Lilfuzzybunny 007 and Bo Lawson. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BoLawson: You tried to ping Andrew, but it didn't succeed. You can only ping one user per comment. I can't merge accounts; I don't have enough permissions. I encourage you to make a new meta post instead. Thanks!